# Maven build fails in Docker Container

Tags: spring-boot, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to create a kind of pipeline to put my application online at AWS so I am running this docker-compose into a EC2.

The error occurs when I run `docker-compose -f docker-compose-java.yml up`

The error is:

```
Starting bookinghub ... done
Attaching to bookinghub
bookinghub   | [INFO] Scanning for projects...
bookinghub   | [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
bookinghub   | [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
bookinghub   | [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
bookinghub   | [INFO] Total time:  0.141 s
bookinghub   | [INFO] Finished at: 2022-11-23T22:22:23Z
bookinghub   | [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
bookinghub   | [ERROR] No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
bookinghub   | [ERROR] 
bookinghub   | [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
bookinghub   | [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
bookinghub   | [ERROR] 
bookinghub   | [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
bookinghub   | [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoGoalSpecifiedException
bookinghub exited with code 1
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM maven:3.8.6-openjdk-18 AS MAVEN_BUILD
RUN microdnf install git -y
RUN mkdir ~/.ssh
COPY id_rsa /root/.ssh/id_rsa
COPY known_hosts /etc/ssh/known_hosts
WORKDIR /root/.ssh/
RUN chmod 400 id_rsa
RUN ssh-keyscan gitlab.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
RUN mkdir ~/repositorio
WORKDIR /repositorio/
RUN git clone git@gitlab.com:booking_hub/grupo_04_bookinghub.git
RUN cd grupo_04_bookinghub/backend/APIrest/APIrest
RUN mvn clean install "-Dmaven.test.skip=true" && mvn package
FROM openjdk:17-slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=MAVEN_BUILD /repositorio/target/APIrest-*.jar /app/APIrest.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Dspring.profiles.active=dev", "-jar", "APIrest.jar"]
```

docker-compose-java.yml

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  #outro container --- backend
  springweb:
    container_name: bookinghub
    build: . #preciso do Dockerfile para gerar a imagem
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - servers
    environment:
      SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: dev

networks:
  servers:
    driver: bridge
```

POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>br.com.APIrest</groupId>
    <artifactId>APIrest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>APIrest</name>
    <description>project for Spring Boot APIrest</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I expect to everytime I run docker-compose the container do a git clone, build the project and run the jar file.

**@EDIT1:**

Alright, so I thought the image was builded with the errors I came across before (which were a lot) and then it wasn't building the image from the scratch (so I think running docker-compose isn't building the image from dockerfile everytime I run the command).

I ran `sudo docker system prune -a --volumes` and ran docker-compose again so the error changed to a build failure which I expected since this instance is not connected to a MySql RDS or MySql container...

Now I will connect the DB to this EC2 and try to run again..

From now, born a new question: the image isn't building every time I run docker-compose, how could I force to re-build the image? My objective here is to when any changes occurs to the main branch of my project, I need to run only once docker-compose and then my backend will self update

**@EDIT2:**

Changed a couple of things at dockerfile

```
FROM maven:3.8.6-openjdk-18 AS MAVENBUILD
RUN microdnf install git -y
RUN mkdir ~/.ssh
COPY id_rsa /root/.ssh/id_rsa
COPY known_hosts /etc/ssh/known_hosts
WORKDIR /root/.ssh/
RUN chmod 400 id_rsa
RUN ssh-keyscan gitlab.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
RUN mkdir ~/repositorio
WORKDIR /repositorio/
RUN git clone git@gitlab.com:booking_hub/grupo_04_bookinghub.git
WORKDIR /repositorio/grupo_04_bookinghub/backend/APIrest/APIrest
RUN mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true && mvn package
FROM openjdk:17
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=MAVENBUILD /repositorio/grupo_04_bookinghub/backend/APIrest/APIrest/target/APIrest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /app/APIrest.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Dspring.profiles.active=dev", "-jar", "APIrest.jar"]
```

application now runs inside the docker container...

Problem solved! :)

Comment: It says to rerun with `-e` did you try that?

Comment: I tried now, nothing changes..

Comment: It’s not supposed to change anything. It shows you the complete stacktrace, which you can post here

Comment: Yeah, I understood it, but with "nothing changes" I mean, literally, nothing changed... No stacktrace showed up, but I added a edit to the question, I think I made it work. Now I have a new error: Step 16/17 : COPY --from=MAVEN_BUILD /repositorio/grupo_04_bookinghub/back/APIrest/APIrest/target/APIrest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /app/APIrest.jar
COPY failed: stat repositorio/grupo_04_bookinghub/back/APIrest/APIrest/target/APIrest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar: file does not exist

Comment: Problem solved, thanks for your attention. I posted how I did it in the edit2